# Update with join and temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have table that called `hanpaka` there I want to update the `cardNum` from temp table the connection between the two is IDMember and MemberId. but updating like this cause multiple cardNum not to the right MemberId why?

```
UPDATE Knowledge4All..Hanpaka
SET CardNum = (c.CardNumber )
FROM #Temp2 c inner join Hanpaka h on IDMember = h.MemberId`
```

Comment: When you use the `update ... from ...` syntax you should then update the alias e.g. `update h ...` otherwise I think it might ignore the join.

Comment: I very much suspect that the above could well treat `Knowledge4All..Hanpaka` and `Hanpaka` as 2 instance of the same object; thus updating *every* row in the table. Also, don't rely on `..` syntax; qualify your schema.

Comment: @Larnu about the `..` this is how the schema buils its fine, I want to know about the query, update it correctly

Comment: It's not "fine", define your schema properly...

Comment: As you have already been warned - don't use three-part names without a very good reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the alias in the `update`:

```
UPDATE h
    SET CardNum = c.CardNumber
FROM #Temp2 c JOIN
     Hanpaka h 
     ON c.IDMember = h.MemberId;
```

SQL Server does allow the table to be repeated in the `update`.  However, it might get confused and your query might be doing a Cartesian product.